# Counting number of first time binary indicators in a time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe that uses binary indicators to reflect whether a customer is live during a particular month. If the customer is live, there is a 1, if not there is a 0. The dataframe looks like the below:

```
Customer    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
11/30/2015  1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
12/31/2015  0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
1/31/2016   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
2/29/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
3/31/2016   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1
4/30/2016   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1
5/31/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1
```

When a customer first becomes live, they get a 1 for the particular month. Therefore when a particular customer has their first 1, this is the month in which they are "new".

I want to add a column at the end of the dataframe which counts the number of "new" customers.

I think the most efficient method of doing this would be to sum the values from row 0 to row i, and count the number of times the sum equals 1. When this sum is greater than 1, then the customer will have been live for 2 months and is not a new customer in the given month.

I have calculated this in excel using this method but I am not clear on how to go about this in Python.

The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
Customer    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   New_Customers
11/30/2015  1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   4
12/31/2015  0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   3
1/31/2016   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
2/29/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   3
3/31/2016   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
4/30/2016   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0
5/31/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0
```

Comment: if a customer *goes live* in their second month do they also get a `1`. In other words are you only counting the first `1` for each customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining a custom `new` function and using `DataFrame.expanding`. I'm not sure why the result of `expanding().apply(new)` requires casting from `float` to `int`, but hey, it works:

```
def new(column):
    return column[-1] and not any(column[:-1])

result = df.expanding().apply(new).sum(axis=1).astype(int)

print(result)

Out:
11/30/2015    4
12/31/2015    3
1/31/2016     0
2/29/2016     3
3/31/2016     0
4/30/2016     0
5/31/2016     0
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Hey... Could you please explain what this line does:
    return column[-1] and not any(column[:-1])

I have been trying to understand but can't quite grasp it

Comment: Try the following: 1. run `help(any)`, 2. run `for thing in column[:-1]: print(thing)`, 3. run `print(bool(0))` and `print(bool(1))`. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a cumulative max which can forward the '1' of each column and sum all  the columns in axis 1 and calculate the difference. 
The first value is given with null that you can fill by summing first row

```
df1 = df[df.columns.difference(['Customer'])]
df['New_customers'] = df1.cummax().sum(1).diff().fillna(df1.loc[0].sum())
```

Out:

```
Customer    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   New_customers
0   11/30/2015  1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   4.0
1   12/31/2015  0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   3.0
2   1/31/2016   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0.0
3   2/29/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   3.0
4   3/31/2016   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0.0
5   4/30/2016   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0.0
6   5/31/2016   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0.0
```